# WebCrypto: Importing rsa key by crypto.subtle.importKey(...)

Tags: encryption, rsa, keys

I generated rsa key by jsbn:

```
{
  "e": "10001",
  "n": "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",
  ...}
```

And I want to import it by `crypto.subtle.importKey`.

This is the error that I find:

> DOMException: The JWK member "n" could not be base64url decoded or contained padding

Does anybody know where is the problem?

Look at the my code below.

```
var keyData = {
    kty: 'RSA',
    e: hexToBase64(rsaJson.e),
    n: hexToBase64(rsaJson.n),
    alg: 'RSA-OAEP-256',
    ext: true
};

var algo = {
    name: 'RSA-OAEP',
    hash: {name: 'SHA-256'}
};

var importedKey = crypto.subtle.importKey('jwk', keyData, algo, false, ['encrypt']).catch(function(err) {
         console.log(err);
     });
```